# In Google Data Studio, how to compare date type variables in calculated field

Tags: date, looker-studio, calculated-field

This is my current calculated field, hours refer to the number of hours an employee worked. I want to null out weekends and specific holidays by specifying the date on a calculated field.

```
   CASE
    WHEN ([day of week]=0 or [day of week]=6 or [date]=DATE(2020,11,02)) AND hours=0
    THEN null
    ELSE hours
    END
```

This produces an error saying invalid formula, invalid input argument. It works tho when I remove the `[date] = DATE(2020,11,02)`

How do I compare data type variables in the calculated field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to separate Month and Day into variables of `Month` and `Day of Month` respectively.

```
CASE
    WHEN ([day of week]=0 or [day of week]=6 or ([Month]=11 AND [Day of Month] = 2) AND hours=0
    THEN null
    ELSE hours
    END
```